# Can there be multiple transactions with the same nonce and from address?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, nonce

I am trying to create a state-channel by signing transactions directly, and I was wondering that the nonce might be troubling in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No, the nonce for a transaction must be exactly one more than the nonce of the previous transaction from that account.